# How to Change Default search provider of IE 9 by registry Editing through C++ program?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, registry, internet-explorer-9

I want to change the default search provider of IE (9) by editing the registry file. I have followed the steps given in the link: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/internet-explorer-tips/change-default-search-engine-ie/.

But when I change DefaultScope value to a scope in SearchScopes, then restart the computer, or open IE, make a search in address bar, or close IE. The value of DefaultScope is restore to previous value.

Why? Or what is my mistake?

**How to change the search provider engine of IE programatically (not in IE, may be through registry, or in my C++ code)? (I write a C++ program that need to change IE's search provider engine)**

> I have written this function for Firefox or Chrome. It works well. 
>   With Firefox, those information is stored in the prefs.js file. I can
>   read or write information requisite to this file easily. With Chrome,
>   those information is stored in two files in user profile folder:
>   Preferences and Web Data files. The Preferences file is a JSON file. I
>   get those information easily by parsing this JSON file. But to set
>   search engine provider information for Chrome. We need to change those
>   information in Web Data file. Web Data file is a SQLite file. I use
>   SQLite library to access this.
>
> With Internet Explorer, I can get those information in that registry
>   path. But I can't set those information with that registry path. So, I
>   think, like Chrome, IE (or registry) needs to change those information
>   somewhere. But I don't know where.

Comment: "How to change the search provider engine in C++? (I write a C++ program that need to change IE's search provider engine )" What do you mean by this?

Comment: No, my program is a tiny program run on Windows 7

Comment: on what platform are you running this program? Desktop or Phone?

Comment: The link you Provided is about changing the search engine in WP! This is very ambiguous and unclear question. Kindly Edit it

Comment: If you need a consistent search provider across your organization then use Group Policy. If you need to do this because you're writing an installer for an application then please kindly desist. As a user, I don't need my preferences changed for me.

Comment: No, this is just a function. I don't know usage of Group Policy. But I look at http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/61275-ie8-default-google-search-via-gpo-some-other-method.html and think that it is like registry.

Comment: What is this function used for? Why would you want a program to change the default search of the user? I cant quite agree with the idea.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318470%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a detailed answer to your question.

There are two options you may choose from use IOpenServiceManager:

```
CComQIPtr<IOpenServiceManager> spManager;
check(spManager.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(OpenServiceManager), CLSCTX_ALL));

CComQIPtr<IOpenService> spService;
check(spManager->InstallService(PU_POSTINSTALL_ANT_SEARCH_PROVIDER_XML, &spService));

if(makeItDefault)
{
    // Request that the user change their search default
    check(spService->SetDefault( TRUE, hPromptParent ));
}
```

or modify the registry:

```
LPCWSTR searchScopesKeyName = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\SearchScopes";

createKey(rootKey, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, searchScopesKeyName);

std::wstring clsidString = findProviderClsid(false);
if( clsidString.empty() )
    clsidString = mc_providerClsidString;

if( makeItDefault )
    setStringValue( rootKey, mc_defaultScopeValueName, clsidString.c_str() );

ATL::CRegKey subKey;
createKey(subKey, rootKey.m_hKey, clsidString.c_str() );

setStringValue( subKey, mc_displayNameValueName, mc_providerName );
setStringValue( subKey, mc_faviconUrlValueName, mc_providerFaviconURL );
setStringValue( subKey, mc_urlValueName, mc_providerURL );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did with second option that rise to my question. Because when restart IE or the computer, those registry settings are restored to previous. I'm trying with first option, but encounter another problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528088/set-the-default-search-engine-provider-of-ie-with-iopenservicemanagerinstallse).

Comment: @user724863, IE doesn't restore its properties at the startup. It is possible that there is one another IE add-on or another app changes thoses values. You may do that using [procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: OMG, that link is a stranger language, maybe Russian. I can't understand. Maybe you right, but I tested on some Win7 systems, those are same result. Some systems are available IE9, some another I have to turn on the Windows features IE9 which I think is clean (no add-on). I'm trying test on WinXP. Thank your very much.

Comment: @user724863, sorry for the invalid link. Try this one: [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/us-en/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: I don't know how to use Procmon.exe to find out the add-on or another app that change those values. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @aviit, Run procmon with adminprivileges, configure the filters (Ctrl+L), select 'Event class' in the left dropdown list, 'is' in the middle one, and 'Registry' in the right one. Press 'Include' button and then 'Apply'. A *.chm file is bundled with with procmon.exe. It should reside in the same directory. It is the help file you may use to find how to perform this operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving a side note that [SetDefault function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849088(v=vs.85).aspx) was deprecated on Microsoft Edge browser. Also, after [KB3148198](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3148198) update, it's blocked. Function will return 
OS_E_CANCELLED instead.