# Set the Default Search Engine Provider of IE with IOpenServiceManager::InstallService

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, search-engine

I would like to set the Default Search Engine Provider of IE with IOpenServiceManager::InstallService:

1. Belong to the link http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_description_elements. I created the **SearchProviderInfo.xml** like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
      <ShortName>Web Search</ShortName>
      <Description>Use Example.com to search the Web.</Description>
      <Tags>example web</Tags>
      <Contact>admin@example.com</Contact>
      <Url type="application/atom+xml"
           template="http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&pw={startPage?}&format=atom"/>
      <Url type="application/rss+xml"
           template="http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&pw={startPage?}&format=rss"/>
      <Url type="text/html" 
           template="http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&pw={startPage?}"/>
      <LongName>Example.com Web Search</LongName>
      <Image height="64" width="64" type="image/png">http://example.com/websearch.png</Image>
      <Image height="16" width="16" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">http://example.com/websearch.ico</Image>
      <Query role="example" searchTerms="cat" />
      <Developer>Example.com Development Team</Developer>
      <Attribution>
        Search data Copyright 2005, Example.com, Inc., All Rights Reserved
      </Attribution>
      <SyndicationRight>open</SyndicationRight>
      <AdultContent>false</AdultContent>
      <Language>en-us</Language>
      <OutputEncoding>UTF-8</OutputEncoding>
      <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    </OpenSearchDescription>
   ```
2. Belong to the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I create the project "SetDefaultHelper" like this:

   ```
       #include <windows.h>
       #include <atlbase.h>
       #include <wininet.h>
       #include <urlmon.h>
       #include <string>
       #include "openservice.h"    
       #pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

   void DisplayUsage()
   {
       wprintf(L"\r\nSetDefaultHelper.exe -- Call SetDefault API on a search provider");
       wprintf(L"\r\n");
       wprintf(L"\r\nUSAGE: SetDefaultHelper.exe <option>");
       wprintf(L"\r\n");
       wprintf(L"\r\nOptions (these are mutually exclusive!):");
       wprintf(L"\r\n");
       wprintf(L"\r\n    /guid <guid>      GUID of an installed search provider");
       wprintf(L"\r\n    /url <url>        URL of an OpenSearch Description file");
       wprintf(L"\r\n");
   }

   int __cdecl wmain(__in int argc, __in_ecount(argc) WCHAR* argv[])
   {
       HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
       BOOL fComInitialized = FALSE;    
       if (3 != argc)
       { 
           DisplayUsage();
       }
       else if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
       {
           fComInitialized = TRUE;
           CComPtr<IOpenServiceManager> spManager;
           hr = spManager.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_OpenServiceManager);    
           if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
           {
               CComPtr<IOpenService> spService;    
               if (0 == _wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/guid"))
               {
                   // Get an IOpenService pointer from the GUID.
                   WCHAR szEscaped[INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH] = L"";
                   DWORD cchEscaped = ARRAYSIZE(szEscaped);
                   hr = UrlEscape(argv[2], szEscaped, &cchEscaped, URL_ESCAPE_SEGMENT_ONLY);    
                   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                   {                        
                       std::wstring wsOsid(L"x-osid:1:search:");
                       wsOsid += szEscaped;
                       hr = spManager->GetServiceByID(wsOsid.c_str(), &spService);
                   }  
               }
               else if (0 == _wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/url"))
               {
                   // Install the provider to get an IOpenService pointer.
                   //CComPtr<IUri> spUri;
                   //hr = CreateUri(argv[2], 0, 0, &spUri);
                   //if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                   //{
                       hr = spManager->InstallService(argv[2], &spService);
                   //}
               }
               else
               {
                   DisplayUsage();
                   hr = E_FAIL;
               }

           if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
           {
               hr = spService-&#62;SetDefault(TRUE, NULL);
           }
       }
   }  

   if (fComInitialized)
   {
       CoUninitialize();
   }

   return hr;


   }
   ```
3. I build the project ok. Both file SetDefaultHelper.exe and SearchProviderInfo.xml are same folder. In the project setting, set Configuration Properties > Debugging > Commands Arguments = /url **absolutePaht/searchProvider.xml**. Then run debug (F10), at line "hr = CreateUri(argv[2], 0, 0, &spUri);", the rusult hr is so stranger. I don't know why. Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

[Resolved]: 
1. Don't need CreateUri //commented 
2. Use a absolutely path.

Comment: Post your hr. Did you try to provide a complete path to the file?

Comment: The problem is resolved. I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use absolute path and `UrlCreateFromPath` to create a `file:///` like URL, pass that URL to `InstallService`.

Between, it seems that your XML has error.

```
            WCHAR szURL[MAX_PATH] = L"";
            DWORD cchURL = ARRAYSIZE(szURL);
            hr = ::UrlCreateFromPath(argv[2], szURL, &cchURL, 0);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = spManager->InstallService(argv[2], &spService);

                // Now we can set it as the default.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = spService->SetDefault(TRUE, NULL);
                    if (hr == OS_E_CANCELLED)
                    {
                        hr = E_ACCESSDENIED;  // by the user!
                    }
                }
            }
```